# ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not working when removing items from list

Tags: android

I am not seeing the fully intended functionality of `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  Renames/modifies work, but removes/deletes do not.
edit:  I am testing on a 4.1.1 phone as well as emulator API 16 (4.1).

`mylistfragment` is my custom ListFragment.

`myadapter` is a standard ArrayAdapter using MyObject.

`mylist` is a ArrayList of MyObject.

1. The **working** rename operation:

   ```
   // rename the db item
   mylistfragment.mylist.get(i).name = "new name";
   (mylistfragment.myadapter).notifyDataSetChanged(); // this works
   ```

   The listview correctly updates to show "new name".
2. The **not working** delete operation:

   ```
   // delete from db
   mylistfragment.mylist.get(i).name = "DELETED";
   mylistfragment.mylist.remove(i);
   (mylistfragment.myadapter).notifyDataSetChanged(); // this does NOT work
   ```

   I see the name of the item get changed to "DELETED", which of course means I did not see the item disappear.

My ArrayList is built from the db when the Fragment is created, so if I recreate my Fragment the item will be gone.  However, I want the item to be gone when I tell the ArrayAdapter to update the views.

Has anyone ever run into this problem or have an idea as to why removing from the arraylist works but isn't reflected by the ListView?

Comment: I have the same problem. I rebuild my list calling my cursor method who is filling my list